# Custom CSS Navigation dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently on my site when I have too many links, the link falls down below the navigation. See my example: https://jsfiddle.net/cn6z13n1/

Is it possible instead to have a `More Links` list item at the far right which will have a dropdown populated with links?

```css
.toolkit_nav {
    background:#dfdfdf;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    padding:0;
}
.toolkit_nav ul {
    margin:0;
}
.toolkit_nav ul .page_item {
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:40px;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0 20px;
}
.toolkit_nav ul .page_item:first-child {
    margin-left:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
.page_item:hover, .current_page_item {
    background:grey;
}
.page_item a {
    color:black;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="toolkit_nav">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="medium-12 columns">
         <ul>
            <li class="page_item page-item-1035 current_page_item"><a href="/introduction/">Introduction</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-1039"><a href="/digital-landscapes/">Digital Landscapes</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-1039"><a href="/digital-landscapes/">Link 4</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-1039"><a href="/digital-landscapes/">Link 3</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-1039"><a href="/digital-landscapes/">Link 2</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-1039"><a href="/digital-landscapes/">Link 1</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-1039"><a href="/digital-landscapes/">Link 5</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes it is, you can write custom JS for that, calculating wheter you have enough space to display every item or not and accordingly change your display, but i suppose there is a library for that somewhere..

Comment: Or at easy you can make a double height nav to show all links so it is all within the navigation (css only possible).. using flex

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know if there is an existing solution or something similar I can hack at? My js skills leave a lot to be desired.

Comment: I wrote custom JS back when i did it, just saw you have an answer that guides you in the right direction, but if i remember right, there are some things you have to consider when doing this, there are some traps you'll fall into really quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do this in js i suggest something like this

1. get the width of the row (max width for nav)
2. loop through the li elements and sum up there width (+ remember to add the width of a "more" element here
3. when sum of width > width of nav element hide the elements
4. add js to your "more" button which shows the hidden elements

Following code is not tested but should give you an idea:

```
var maxWidth = $('#nav').width();
var moreWidth = $('#more').width(); // li "more" element

var sumWidth = moreWidth;
$('#nav li').each(function() {
    sumWidth += $(this).width();
    if(sumWidth > maxWidth) {
       $(this).addClass('hide'); // add css for hide class
    }
});

$('#more').on('click', function() {
   $('#nav .hide').fadeIn(100);
   // You will need more code here to place it correctly, maybe append the elements in an container
});
```

Here an example with your fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cn6z13n1/3/

Note: this is just a rough draft, you might to calc paddings etc. to make this work rly good

Edit: updated example with $(window).resize() function

https://jsfiddle.net/cn6z13n1/6/

Comment: Many thanks for such a detailed response.
I have added your code to my example and wondered if you could assist a little further? https://jsfiddle.net/cn6z13n1/4/ Basically when I resize my page, I need `Link 2` to be added into the `More...` dropdown list.

Comment: Hi Frank, I have tried this with the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cn6z13n1/3/ but it doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Will this kind of menu help you out ? http://designmodo.com/create-css3-mega-menu/

Comment: @michaelmcgurk to make this snippet run resize the rendered part to when the navigation breaks, then hit run again. You could attach the resize function to the given code to make it more dynamic

Comment: here the full example with dynamic resize update https://jsfiddle.net/cn6z13n1/6/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change you HTML slightly but this will work.

```css
        .toolkit_nav {
          background: #dfdfdf;
          width: 100%;
          height: 40px;
          padding: 0;
        }
        .toolkit_nav ul {
          margin: 0;
        }
        .toolkit_nav ul .page_item {
          display: inline-block;
          line-height: 40px;
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0 20px;
        }
        .toolkit_nav ul .page_item:first-child {
          margin-left: 0;
          padding-left: 0;
        }
        .page_item:hover,
        .current_page_item {
          background: grey;
        }
        .page_item a {
          color: black;
          font-size: 0.9em;
          font-weight: 400;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        /* NEW STUFF */
        .sub-nav,
        .sub-nav li {
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .more {
          position: relative;
        }
        .more>ul {
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          top: 100%;
          padding: 0
        }
        .more:hover>ul {
          display: block;
        }
        .more>ul>li {
          display: block;
          width: 100%;
          clear: both;
          text-align: center;
        }
        .toolkit_nav ul.sub-nav .page_item:first-child {
          padding: 0 20px;
        }
```

```html
<nav class="toolkit_nav">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns">

      <ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-1035 current_page_item"><a href="/introduction/">Introduction</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-1039"><a href="/digital-landscapes/">Digital Landscapes</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-1039"><a href="/digital-landscapes/">Link 4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-1039"><a href="/digital-landscapes/">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-1039"><a href="/digital-landscapes/">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-1039 more"><a href="/digital-landscapes/">More...</a>
          <ul class="sub-nav">
            <li class="page_item page-item-1039"><a href="/digital-landscapes/">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-1039"><a href="/digital-landscapes/">Link 5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: That is brilliant, @Aaron. I guess the main thing I need to figure out is how to do this dynamically. So to populate that `More` area with links using jQuery.

Comment: aah, so you're unable to alter your HTML. That's a shame.

Comment: That's just part of the solution, that is hardcoded HTML and CSS and won't fix the issue, if the display will be wider, the _more_ link is uncalled for and if the screen would be even smaller, the more would be overlapping the screen too.

Comment: I guess I could use a while loop to generate the list of links in the `More` but then how do I decide what to show/hide? It's tricky.

Comment: @Tarekis That's exactly the issue. Do you know of any existing fixes out there for such an issue?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk have you considered changing your menu to a pure dropdown on smaller screens?

Comment: I couldn't find anything no, well i know how to do it, but tbh creating a full-packed custom solution is a tad bit too much for a SE question imo. If you'd appreciate that, i could explain to you how to do it clean yourself, if so we can move to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100400/further-discussing).

Comment: @Aaron Thank you, however, I think the issue will still arise on Desktop where there are too many links. I guess I could switch to vertical menu after the first break point.